# What terminal-based network speed tests are available?

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line, ssh

I'm looking to find a way to test my internet speed at home through ssh.  Does anyone know a terminal app that can give me calculations similar info to speedtest.net?

It would also be really cool if there was something that would do tests based on common internet ports too (i.e. web, torrent, etc) so you can see if you're getting throttled by your ISP.

Comment: Or you can use `iperf` as was suggested in this hint: http://askubuntu.com/questions/7976/how-do-you-test-the-network-speed-betwen-two-boxes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may use [nload](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nload) ([Install nload](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/nload)) for this purpose. Sample output:

[image]

You can install `nload` by this command:

```
sudo apt-get install nload
```

Also available in software center.

Comment: this works perfect using the -u and -t options.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

**Update Nov 2016:** I discontinued it. Please use another provider i.e. Init7 with http://speedtest.init7.net/10GB.dat

**Original answer:**

There is also this easy "speedtest":

```
wget -O/dev/null speedtest.pixelwolf.ch
```

This gives you the current speed and it is available up to 100 megabits per second.

Comment: Could you plz explain the `-0/dev/null` bit?

Comment: quote from `man wget`: `-O FILE` or `--output-document=FILE` is where to save the result of wget command. And `/dev/null` is a device in Linux systems which is not really existent. Everything saved there or sent to there will be ignored and it does not use space on your filesystem. Otherwise you would have to delete the saved file of the speedtest.

Comment: but why is it then `-0/dev/null` and not `-0 /dev/null`; does the space not matter? does it work with _and_ without the space?

Comment: Yep, works with and without. And it is O (like Oscar) and not 0 (zero).

Comment: For me it failed. 

`--2016-11-06 06:33:56--  http://speedtest.pixelwolf.ch/
Resolving speedtest.pixelwolf.ch (speedtest.pixelwolf.ch)... failed: No address associated with hostname.
wget: unable to resolve host address 'speedtest.pixelwolf.ch'`

Comment: Sorry for that. I did not continue the file (I did it for a few years since 2012 though). Currently I use "wget -O /dev/null http://speedtest.init7.net/10GB.dat" which is provided by the Gigabit provider Init7 in Switzerland.

Answer (score 6):

How about netperf? http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man1/netperf.1.html

## [netperf](http://packages.ubuntu.com/netperf) [image: Install netperf]

Quoting from the man page:

> Netperf  is  a benchmark that can be used to measure various aspects of
>       networking performance.  Currently, its focus is on bulk data  transfer
>       and  request/response  performance  using  either  TCP  or UDP, and the
>       Berkeley Sockets interface. In  addition,  tests  for  DLPI,  and  Unix
>       Domain Sockets, tests for IPv6 may be conditionally compiled-in.

Comment: What a brilliant program.

Comment: Keeps giving me an error in 10.04: netperf: send_tcp_stream: data socket connect failed: Address family not supported by protocol. any ideas on an example usage?

Comment: TCP Stream Performance

The TCP stream performance test is the default test type for the netperf program. The simplest test is performed by entering the command:

/opt/netperf/netperf -H remotehost

which will perform a 10 second test between the local system and the system identified by remotehost. The socket buffers on either end will be sized according to the systems' default and all TCP options (e.g. TCP_NODELAY) will be at their default settings.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution I know is to simply use

```
wget -O/dev/null http://releases.ubuntu.com/saucy/ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso
```

wget will provide you with file size, download time, and download speed.

If you need more complex solution, have a look at [iperf](http://iperf.sourceforge.net/). This solution is however more complicated, because it requires more set-up, and is not straight-forward (for example it requires a server with higher speed than yours).

Comment: I'm more looking for a package that will return the calculations as a more simple string so I can setup a script that will put those into a database and let me run analytics on my connection.  Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: I guess you may need to write a small bash script that would format the wget output to a simple string (and might even run test periodically), but when it comes to measuring speed, I doubt if there is anything that will return just a string, most software says lots of thing in addition, and hopes the user will be happy with the details it provided, so I suspect you may need to format the output manually (or with a script)

Comment: @RafałCieślak Could you plz explain the `-0/dev/null` bit?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty sure! It tells wget to write downloaded data to /dev/null, so in fact everything that is downloaded does not get stored/saved anywhere, as it would be silly to waste one's disk space to test network speed.

Comment: @RafałCieślak thanks; I had never heard about the "null device" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/null before; interesting stuff, slowling expanding my *nix knowledge... Elsewhere I've seen `wget --output-document=/dev/null http://speedtest..` How does this differ to `-0/dev/null` ?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty These two options are exactly the same. `-0` is a synonym for `--optput-document`. Using `man wget` will help you explore it's all flags!

Answer (score 2):

you also can use iftop while transferring files

Answer (score 0):

```
scp username@remoteserver.com:/some-file.ext .
```

will show something like :

> some-file.ext
>   24%   16KB  13.0KB/s   00:03 ETA^