# How to check gigabit connection between 2 (X) ubuntu computers?

Tags: networking, lan

I have an ethernet 10/100 switch. this connection is working properly (to my cablemodem router, so all computers are connected to internet).

I have just bought a Gigabit switch that I am about to use instead of the other. The intented purpose is to be able to share quickly between these computers.

How to check that I am achieving Gigabit speed with my new switch between my Xubuntu / Ubuntu 14.04 computers in the lan?

I am not sharing yet between computers or created and workgroup, as I still need to learn how to do it. This is just information for anyone who will want to help to keep in mind.

Thanks

Alex

Comment: I've closed this against a question I answered a fair while ago. It still applies for basic speed testing between Ubuntu machines. Just remember that a connection will only go as fast as the slowest component. Both network adaptors need to be gigabit, the switch needs to be gigabit and the cabling needs to be within a hundred meters (usually not an issue) and of good, uninterfered quality.

Comment: Excellent, I found it. http://askubuntu.com/questions/7976/how-do-you-test-the-network-speed-betwen-two-boxes/7977#7977 thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to make you hunt. It's linked at the top of your question now.