# How can I create heavy traffic on a ethernet link from the command line?

Tags: networking, command-line, server

I seem to have a network problem when one of my server machine moves a large amount of data over the network link it is on.  I am sure that in the past I have been able to pipe random data to given IPv4 address or MAC address from the command line for a fixed amount of time.  This is very simple way to test if traffic load on a spefici link is the cause of the problem.

I am not that worried about calculating the link speed, I would just like to try and saturate or at least heavily load (~100Mbps) the link.  Being able to easily do it from a typical Ubuntu 16.04 command line with basic tools would allow me to easily ssh to a machine (set up a GNU Screen session) and target another machine.  I could then work through links or hosts to work out which of them (if any) trigger my networking issue.

Comment: Take a look here, multiple solutions are described :
[http://serverfault.com/questions/146362/generate-a-limited-amount-of-random-network-traffic-between-2-hosts](http://serverfault.com/questions/146362/generate-a-limited-amount-of-random-network-traffic-between-2-hosts)

Comment: sudo ping -f -s 65507 <IP>  #(65507 is limit of icmp packet size, more than that is ping of death )

Comment: This would be helpful :http://askubuntu.com/q/7976/497359

Comment: @SeverusTux thank you. That had something like I remember.  "You can do pretty much the same thing with plain old nc (netcat) if you're that way inclined. On the server machine `nc -vvlnp 12345 >/dev/null` And the client can pipe a gigabyte of zeros through dd over the nc tunnel.
`dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=1K | nc -vvn 10.10.0.2 12345`"  I have used /dev/urandom before as a source too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this using Netcat.

On the target machine (that will receive the data) set up netcat to receive data on a port (12345 in the example below) and pipe it to /dev/null.  /dev/null is used as it should be the fastest place to send the data to, if you use a file on disk there is a chance it will slow the transfer.

```
nc -vvlnp 12345 >/dev/null
```

Now on the source machine (that will send the data) set up netcat to transmit a set of data to the target machine.  This can be /dev/zero or /dev/random if you want to ensure no compression is taking place.  In the example below 1M bit lumps of data are sent 1k times to the target at address 10.10.0.2.

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=1K | nc -vvn 10.10.0.2 12345
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using iperf. More details can be found here https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=iperf&sektion=1&manpath=freebsd-release-ports.
It is supported on multiple platforms including windows, so there shouldn't be any issues with varying platforms as well.