# Is it possible to perform speed test with any Ubuntu server?

Tags: server, download-speed, testing

I have a home server with Ubuntu and I want to measure download and upload speed in my LAN. Is there any program for Ubuntu that will help me do this?

Comment: @muru No. I don't want to test my server's internet connection speed but I want to test the LAN transfer speed between my laptop and server.

Comment: That's https://askubuntu.com/q/7976/158442 then

Comment: @user535733 Yes, but the same answer is already here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- a standard tool is [IPerF](https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/diagnostics/install-iperf-to-diagnose-network-speed-in-linux/) or it's graphical frontend [JPerF](http://www.nwlab.net/know-how/JPerf/)

( https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-test-the-network-speedthroughput-between-two-linux-servers/ )

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for :)

Answer (score -1):

Well, you said download/upload speed and LAN, so I'm not sure which you actually want.

To test download/upload speed of your Internet connection:

Yes. It's is possible.  With the project: https://github.com/sindresorhus/fast-cli

If you have node installed, just run `npm install --global fast-cli`

Then you can use `fast` to start the test.

If you don't have node installed, you can install it with `apt install nodejs`

To test your LAN speed, you'll need a second computer and install `iperf` on both.

Run one side as a server, the other side as the client.

On ubuntu, you can install iperf with `apt install iperf`, on MacOS `brew install iperf` for other operating systems you'll have to google.

Comment: What about www.openspeedtest.com ?

Comment: I want to measure tranfer speed between my laptop and server in the LAN.

Comment: Then iperf is the way to go.